# main () not waiting for update of file dialog in golang using fyne for file dialog

Tags: go, fyne

I would like to use a file dialog to select a directory for further use in **Go**. To select the directory i am using a Fyne file dialog as the rest of the application uses Fyne as well. I managed to create a simple test application:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/dialog"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

var save_dir string = "NoPathYet!"

func chooseDirectory(w fyne.Window) string {
    dialog.ShowFolderOpen(func(dir fyne.ListableURI, err error) {
        if err != nil {
            dialog.ShowError(err, w)
            return
        }
        if dir != nil {

            fmt.Println(dir.Path())
            save_dir = dir.Path() // here value of save_dir shall be updated!

        }
        fmt.Println(save_dir)

    }, w)
    return save_dir
}

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("FileDialogTest")

    hello := widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!")
    w.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
        hello,
        widget.NewButton("Go Get Directory!", func() {
            hello.SetText(chooseDirectory(w)) // Text of hello updated by return value
        }),
    ))
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 500))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

It does not work properly, the label *hello* is updated prior to the return of the value, somehow...

When the button **"Go Get Directory!"** is clicked the function *chooseDirectory* should called and the return value should be set as text in the *hello*-Label.

I am a Golang-Newbie, so my question may be silly for more experienced Go programmers. In any case I would appreciate help!

Thanks in advance,

Vinz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember the point of callback function is not to wait. In your code the `chooseDirectory(w)` is always returned before the user selects any folder. So, you should directly update `hello` label text within the callback of `ShowFolderOpen`.

Here is working code as expected.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/dialog"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func chooseDirectory(w fyne.Window, h *widget.Label) {
    dialog.ShowFolderOpen(func(dir fyne.ListableURI, err error) {
        save_dir := "NoPathYet!"
        if err != nil {
            dialog.ShowError(err, w)
            return
        }
        if dir != nil {
            fmt.Println(dir.Path())
            save_dir = dir.Path() // here value of save_dir shall be updated!
        }
        fmt.Println(save_dir)
        h.SetText(save_dir)
    }, w)
}

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("FileDialogTest")

    hello := widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!")
    w.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
        hello,
        widget.NewButton("Go Get Directory!", func() {
            chooseDirectory(w, hello) // Text of hello updated by return value
        }),
    ))
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 500))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks very much indeed for your response and your help! Coming from Python, there several changes that I still have to learn. :-).